# loop for Stylus value

Tags: stylus

I want this

```
long_shadow()
    text-shadow: 1px 1px, 2px 2px, 3px 3px, 4px 4px, 5px 5px, ... ,Npx Npx
```

I've tried this

```
calculate_shadow()
    $shadows = ''
    for i in 1..6
        $shadows += '%spx %spx, ' % (i i)
    $shadows += '0px 0px'

long_shadow()
    text-shadow: {calculate_shadow_base()}
```

But this will print all the string concatenate procedure

then this

```
calculate_shadow()
    $shadows = ''
    for i in 1..6
        $shadows += '%spx %spx, ' % (i i)
    $shadows += '0px 0px'

long_shadow()
    text-shadow: calculate_shadow_base()
```

It will print

```
text-shadow: '1px 1px, 2px 2px, 3px 3px, 4px 4px, 5px 5px'
```

How can I remove the Quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the {} around your function call, that's for interpolation :

```
calculate_shadow()
    $shadows = ''
    for i in 1..6
        $shadows += '%spx %spx, ' % (i i)
    $shadows + '0px 0px'

long_shadow()
    text-shadow: unquote(calculate_shadow())

body
    long_shadow()
```

Comment: I've tried this, but the value display as String. It will print as text-shadow: '1px 1px, 2px 2px'. This won't work at all. I need to remove the QUOTE

Comment: Try calling unquote() on it.